# Difference between SQL Outer JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wanted to know the difference between these two SQL queries..
Note: Foreign Key = dept_no

Query1:

```
SELECT emp_no, emp_name, emp.dept_no, dept_name, loc
from emp,dept
WHERE emp.dept (+)= dept.dept_no;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT emp_no, emp_name, emp.dept_no, dept_name, loc
from emp,dept
WHERE emp.dept = dept.dept_no(+);
```

Basically my question is about the position of the Outer Join.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The position of the `outer join` (left or right) determines from which of the tables to return *all rows* even if no matching rows from the related table exist.  Therefore...

The first (`left outer join`) will return all employee information (all rows from `emp`) even if not associated with a department.

The second (`right outer join`) will return all department names & department numbers (all rows from `dept`), even if no employees belong to that department.

Answer (score 4):

You tagged your question `mysql` but the special outer join syntax you're using is a proprietary invention of Oracle.

MySQL does not support the `(+)` join modifier syntax in any position.

Why not use ANSI SQL-92 syntax for `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`?  Then your queries would be clear, and would work in both Oracle and MySQL.

```
SELECT emp_no, emp_name, emp.dept_no, dept_name, loc
FROM emp LEFT OUTER JOIN dept ON emp.dept = dept.dept_no
```

Comment: wow! i did NOT know that.. thanks for sharing that! i though they wer just two ways of writing the same thing.

Comment: AFAIK, Oracle had to come up with something to do outer joins in the 1980's, before ANSI SQL defined their standard syntax for it.  Every RDBMS vendor now supports the standard syntax, so it's unnecessary for anyone to continue using vendors' old proprietary syntax.

Comment: Agree, there is no excuse to ever use implicit syntax. It is unclear, easy to create bad mistakes in what is returned (Accidental cross joins) and harder to maintain. There are no pluses at all to using it and many minuses.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic difference between `Table 1 (LEFT outer join) Table 2` and `Table 1 (RIGHT outer join) Table 2`, wherein the former gives you all records from Table 1, including those missing an association in Table 2, and the latter is vice versa.